# Additional Shipping Fee on COD for Specific Country Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I've a store setup on Magento 2.2.3

I use two payment methods: COD, Credit Card Payment

There are 2 allowed countries (for example A and B)

For `Country:A` shipping is flat (i.e. 10 USD)

For `Country:B` shipping is calculated according to weight table

What I want: For `Country:A` when user selects `COD` as payment method, additional shipping charges (5 USD) should be charged (i.e. 10 USD + 5 USD = 15 USD)

How do I achieve this in Magento 2.2.3 so that I could set additional shipping charges from admin and User is shown additional charges at front?

Kindly tell me if there's any free existing module/extension available for this.

Comment: Do you want to show the additional charges as separate or in the shipping charges?

Comment: in shipping charges